# AWS Lambda and Gateway API - blue/green deployment with cloudformation

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-route53, blue-green-deployment

When deploying the lambda function with Gateway API using cloudformation template, I want to put Gateway APIs created with different stages behind route53, so can use the weighted trafficking for blue/green deployment. Is it possible to automate the whole process without manual logging to the console to configure?

Answer (score 5):

You won't be able to do this. Your Route53 aliases will not be understood by API Gateway. There currently isn't an out-of-the box blue/green solution for API gateway and Lambda.

Comment: Bob, any links you could share for weighted trafficking blue/green deployment for Gateway API sitting in front of lambda?

Comment: The only way to achieve this today is to have a Lambda (or API Gateway + Lambda) in between the 2 lambdas you are trying to balance. I don't have any docs as this is not an ideal configuration. We hope to add support for such deployments to API Gateway in the future.

Comment: Adding another lambda to split traffics will incur more cost and latency, which may not be a preferred approach... if without Gateway API, for lambda itself with route53, any reference architecture for weighted blue/green deployment?

Comment: @Hammer not currently, due to the limitations noted.

Comment: @Bob Kinney: are you guys planning to create a feature that permits blue / green deployment using API gateway?

Comment: @p.magalhaes As mentioned in my previous comment: we hope to add support for such deployments in the future, but I cannot commit to a timeline as to when they would be available.

Comment: Erm I use the basepath mapping in API gateway to do this since it updates very quickly and perform the switch on certain conditions like error thresholds using SNS - give me a wee while and I'll do an answer.

Comment: @BobKinney any progress or clearer vision on possibility to have any such out of box feature coming out sooner? We are using Lambda and APIGateway heavily for our up coming website and willing to deploy Blue-Green way for our production. If any potential time lines for such AWS service, we would rather wait for that instead of going ahead with any engineered work around.

Comment: @AshwinGupta Both API Gateway and Lambda have launched features supporting this use case. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/implementing-canary-deployments-of-aws-lambda-functions-with-alias-traffic-shifting/
https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/11/amazon-api-gateway-supports-canary-release-deployments/

Comment: @bob yeah, I came to know from re:invent recordings. Time to try that out now :-) thanks

Comment: @BobKinney the solution is undoubtedly wonderful but I failed to find the correct syntax for SAM Template (CF) file to implement it. While I keep doing hit-n-try, if you have got any example in knowledge, to implement Canary deployments for Lambdas using SAM, kindly share.

Comment: I found an half cooked example but should be good to go. However the it appears that, AWS Code Deploy would be must to use the fully out of box feature. Is that really so?

Comment: SAM support is not yet available, but should be coming soon. Code Deploy is not *required* for weighted aliases but is one mechanism that can be used to control the roll out.

Comment: @AshwinGupta If you have further questions or issues, I encourage you to create a new question here or post on our forums.

Answer (score 2):

Blue/Green and Canary deployments are now supported by AWS API Gateway.

> Another traffic shifting pattern is enabling blue/green deployments. This near zero-downtime release enables traffic to shift to the new live environment (green) while still keeping the old production environment (blue) warm in case a rollback is necessary. Since API Gateway allows you to define what percentage of traffic is shifted to a particular environment; this style of deployment can be an effective technique. Since blue/green deployments are designed to reduce downtime, many customers adopt this pattern for production changes.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/wellarchitected/latest/serverless-applications-lens/bluegreen-deployments.html

Answer (score 0):

@Bob,

I've seen a few answers from you on this, I have asked on another, I have a working solution that relies on the SWITCH being the basepath mapping on the APIG stage.

Although AWS just introduced Canary but it relies on CodeDeploy which a lot of us don't use when using things like the Serverless framework.

The idea is simple, when you deploy you switch your basepath mapping between stages(blue/green) if you fire an SNS event for every non 2XX error once you reach a certain threshold you can simply turn the basepath mapping back and it works instantly?

Is there any reason why this wouldn't work?